# Interesting behavior of chain call of stored procedures in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, python-2.6

I'm using MySQL 5.5, Python 2.6 and MySQLdb package

What I have:

Procedure #1

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS log_create;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE log_create
(
    IN p_log_type_id INT,
    IN p_body TEXT
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log(
        log_type_id,
        body
    )
    VALUES(
        p_log_type_id,
        p_body
    );
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as log_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Procedure #2

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS http_request_log_create;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE http_request_log_create
(
    IN p_log_type_id INT,
    IN p_body TEXT,
    IN p_host VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_port SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    IN p_url VARCHAR(1024),
    IN p_method VARCHAR(8),
    IN p_customer_id VARCHAR(128),
    IN p_protocol VARCHAR(8),
    IN p_query_parameters VARCHAR(1024),
    IN p_duration DECIMAL(3,3) UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
    CALL log_create(p_log_type_id, p_body);
    SET @v_log_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO http_request_log (
        log_id,
        host,
        port,
        url,
        method,
        customer_id,
        protocol,
        query_parameters,
        duration
    )
    VALUES (
        @v_log_id,
        p_host,
        p_port,
        p_url,
        p_method,
        p_customer_id,
        p_protocol,
        p_query_parameters,
        p_duration
    );
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as http_request_log_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Procedure #3:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS api_error_log_create;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE api_error_log_create
(
    IN p_log_type_id INT,
    IN p_body TEXT,
    IN p_host VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_port SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    IN p_url VARCHAR(1024),
    IN p_method VARCHAR(8),
    IN p_customer_id VARCHAR(128),
    IN p_protocol VARCHAR(8),
    IN p_query_parameters VARCHAR(1024),
    IN p_duration DECIMAL(3,3) UNSIGNED,
    IN p_message VARCHAR(512),
    IN p_stack_trace TEXT,
    IN p_version VARCHAR(8)
)
BEGIN
    CALL http_request_log_create(p_log_type_id, p_body, p_host, p_port, p_url, p_method, p_customer_id, p_protocol, p_query_parameters, p_duration);
    INSERT INTO api_error_log (
        http_request_log_id,
        message,
        stack_trace,
        version
    )
    VALUES (
        LAST_INSERT_ID(),
        p_message,
        p_stack_trace,
        p_version
    );

  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as api_error_log_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see, I'm using chain of stored procedures calls and this works fine for me. But...

```
def create_api_error_log(self, connection, model):
    result = self.create_record(
        connection,
        'api_error_log_create',
        (model.log_type_id,
         model.body,
         model.host,
         model.port,
         model.url,
         model.method,
         model.customer_id,
         model.protocol,
         model.query_parameters,
         model.duration,
         model.message,
         model.stack_trace,
         model.version,
         model.api_error_log_id))
     return ApiErrorLogCreateResult(result)
```

Here, **result** variable contains dictionary:
    {'log_id': _some_int_}

**log_id**, **LOG_ID!!!**, not required **api_error_log_id**.

As I understood, cursor returns as result of the first select statement  result in the stored procedures call.

I need **api_error_log_id** value corrected returned from the function call.
I know how to get it in few other ways, but I need to know if it is possible to obtain required id in my way?

**Edit 1**:

```
def create_record(self, conn, proc_name, proc_params):
    result = self.common_record(conn, proc_name, proc_params, 'fetchone')
    return result and result.itervalues().next()

def common_record(self, conn, proc_name, proc_params=(), result_func='', method='callproc'):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    eval('cursor.%s' % method)(proc_name, proc_params)
    result = result_func and eval('cursor.%s' % result_func)() or cursor.rowcount > 0
    cursor.close()
    #print 'sql: ', proc_name, proc_params
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is a quite simple.

All the result sets from select statements during the last query (chaing of stored procedures calls) is available for
reading. By default, cursor contains the first select result available for fetching. You can use

```
cursor.nextset()
```

to check if there are any other select results. This method returns True of False. If True, you can use fetch methods to obtain results of the next select statement.

Cheers.